# Changing the name of parent menuitems in odoo 10

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-10

I want to change the name of main module name in my third party apps in odoo 10. [image: The circle one]

I want to change the Maintenance name to Asset name. How can I do that? How can I change that using inherit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

```xml
<record id="maintenance.menu_maintenance_title" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name='name'>Asset</field>
</record>
```

The id is the xml id of the parent menuitem in maintenance module and you have to change the field `name`.